# Heated Adamantine "Bricks" as a Fuel Source

Tags: science-based, physics, materials, steampunk, thermodynamics

I was pondering a situation where adamantine could be harvested from deep underground, amongst lavaflows, to work as a fuel source.

### Facts:

The Adamantine has been heated for millennia at thousands of degrees C. Additionally, adamantine is actually a really terrible conductor and a great insulator; so it took a long time to heat it up, and I presume it will radiate heat for a long time before cooling off.

A harvested "brick," might weigh 100kg--however, being 3 times denser than iron, it's only about 0.455 cubic feet big, or 0.0129 cubic meters.

### Application:

I was wondering if these factors might make them suitable as a fuel source. That, due to their unique properties, they might radiate heat for a long time at a temperature suitable to power a steam boiler. If this worked, you could save a lot of weight.

### Question

The main question is if these bricks could plausibly radiate enough heat at a high enough temperature for enough time to be useful. Do you think that, given a fictional material, that might be possible?

Comment: Given that "adamantine is actually a really terrible conductor and a great insulator", wouldn't you expect the outer layer (perhaps a few atoms thick) to cool down to "room temperature" while the inner core remains hot, trapping all the heat energy inside?

Comment: fuel for what? cooking sure, powering a car no

Comment: Have you heard of radioisotope thermoelectric generators?  They're what NASA and other space programs use on outer-system probes.  Basically the same sort of idea as you're looking for, since they're powered by a piece of material which stays hot for a very long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: If your adamantine is basically made of matter, then the answer is probably "No". You can't store enough energy as heat in a small chunk of matter to be useful; you need some other way to store it as chemical or nuclear potential. Nuclear steam engines are fine, but they do have some new risks compared to the regular kind!

---

The two things that spoil your plan are a) the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) (which describe the power radiated from a black-body, which your hot bricks probably are) and b) the [equipartition theoren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Ideal_gas_law) (which relates the temperature of something to the energy of its consitutents).

[Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html) (which includes a nice radiative cooling time calculator) suggests using a [nice simple model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Ideal_gas_law) for the energy content of your hot ball as $E = N \frac{3}{2}k_BT$ where $N$ is the number of particles, $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $T$ is the temperature of the object.

Throwing these together and doing a little calculus that I won't try to repeat here gets you a nice simple cooling rate equation:

$$t_{cooling} = \frac{Nk_B}{8\sigma \pi r^2}\left[ \frac{1}{T_{final}^3} - \frac{1}{T_{initial}^3} \right]$$

You can get $N$ from $\frac{mN_A}{M}$ where $m$ is the mass of your sphere, $N_A$ is Avogadro's constant and $M$ is the molar mass of whatever your ball is made of.

<sub>(note: this is a *radiative* cooling time calculator so cooling via conduction and convection, which will happen when you're trying to drive a steam engine, will be *much faster*!)</sub>

A high $T_{initial}$ means that radiative power rates are high (they're proportional to the *fourth* power of temperature!) so you lose energy quickly. $N$ is going to be relatively high for your dense metal, but it isn't *ridiculously* dense and so it'll only put off cooling for so long. If you material has a super low thermal conductivity then the *center* will remain hot but the outside will still cool quickly. You can't power a steam engine for long on your hot brick, because either heat won't come out quickly enough to provide you with enough power, or you'll simply run out of heat and not have power for long enough to be useful.

---

As a worked example, a 100kg ball of your adamantium (assuming its molar mass is 3x that of iron) has a radius of ~10cm, and in a vacuum will cool from 1000K to 500K in about 40 minutes, neglecting internal thermal conductivity. In air (or water, or steam) this will happen much more quickly.

Its initial radiated power is ~7.2kW or ~9.6HP in more steampunky units (into a 0K vacuum; it'll be less than this on Earth which is a bit warmer than that). By the time it has cooled to 500K, the power is only ~450W or ~0.6HP. Heat engines being what they are, you will have substantial efficiency losses here of at least 50% and probably more (and efficiency will drop as the brick temperatures drops).

Given its considerable weight and difficulty of acquisition, I'm not sure this compares favorably with chemical fuels. Consider the [Copeland steam bicycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland_steam_bicycle) for a fine example of "real world steampunk":

[image: Drawing of 1884 Copeland steam bicycle. Page 52. Illustration by Hendee Manufacturing Co.]

(image source: [wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Copeland_steam_bicycle_1884_The_Standard_Reference_Work.png))

> The steam-powered engine produced 4 horsepower at 2600 rpm with a 100-pound (45 kg) boiler around the steering column with the water heated by kerosene. A simple leather belt drove the large rear wheel, yielding a top speed of around 15 miles per hour (24 km/h).

It doesn't describe what the working range is, but I'll bet it is easier to come by kerosene than adamantium so refuelling will be a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Didn't know what formulas to look up for this, and wasn't sure how fast something like this would cool. I've selected your answer, since unless you're mistaken on some point, I don't think I'll need another one. Not sure what they can use as something more efficient as coal. May have to resort to a fully magic source.

Comment: @Salli most flashier steampunk requires magic, but isn't always explicit about it. Problem with real-world fuels is that [anthracite coal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density) is just _really good_, and it is very difficult to improve on.

Comment: If adamantine could have allotropes with differing binding energy, could these store enough additional energy to make a difference?

Comment: @ooak maybe! it makes for a nice alternative to burning stuff (and works without air) but high-energy-density metastable fuels are the sorts of things that should make the hairs on the back of your neck raise up. Kerosene powered bicycle: fine. _Nitroglycerine_ powered bicycle: maaaaaybe not.

Comment: Is Jan's idea in the other answer a reasonable possibility?

Answer (score 3):

If your Adamantine is made of something resembling real atoms, then StarfishPrime's answer tells you all. But Adamantine doesn't exist in reality so you can give it any property you like, such as a [specific heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) a few orders of magnitude larger than what realistic materials have. The way to do that on the atomic level is to let adamantine be made of atoms (or other constituent particles) much smaller and lighter than real atoms, but much more of them. The number of particles per kg is (I think) more or less proportional to the material's specific heat capacity.

A material with an extremely high specific heat capacity would contain a lot of energy for a given temperature. The radiated power as it cools will still drop exponentially as Starfish explained, but with a very high specific heat capacity that drop may be very slow. If it takes days for a block of adamantine to cool from 500°C to 400°C while giving off several horsepower of heat that might be a very useful source of fuel. It's just a matter of cost of obtaining it vs how much heat energy it supplies and how useful that energy is for you.

Although if the adamantine is at thousands of degrees C it may be difficult to handle, as any metal and most rocks and ceramics it touches would melt. You would need to pack it in a thick layer of refractory insulating material, but I don't think that existed in the steam age, though you could just invent your own. Even modern high temperature insulators have melting temperatures below 2000 °C as far as I can find quickly.